# How to get data status wise after grouping?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get count of different statuses for bookings for each event and some other data. Each row should represent an event.

So I have an events table and a bookings table.

Events table has `id, name, max_allowed`
Bookings table has `id,event_id,status`

Status can be booked, canceled, waitlisted.

I want to get data for all events with the count for each status.
So I need these columns -

```
event_id
booked_count
canceled_count
waitlisted_count
remaining_slots - (max_allowed - booked_count)
occupancy_rate - booked_count/max_allowed
```

Sample data:

Events

```
| id    | name      | max_allowed   |
|----   |---------  |-------------  |
| 1     | Yoga      | 5             |
| 2     | Boxing    | 2             |
| 3     | Pilates   | 5             |
```

Bookings

```
| id    | event_id  | status        |
|----   |---------- |------------   |
| 1     | 1         | booked        |
| 2     | 1         | booked        |
| 3     | 2         | booked        |
| 4     | 2         | canceled      |
| 5     | 2         | booked        |
| 6     | 2         | waitlisted    |
| 7     | 3         | booked        |
| 8     | 3         | booked        |
| 9     | 3         | booked        |
```

Output:

```
| event_id  | booked_count  | canceled_count    | waitlisted_count  | remaining_slots   | occupancy_rate    |
|---------- |-------------- |----------------   |------------------ |-----------------  |----------------   |
| 1         | 2             | 0                 | 0                 | 3                 | 0.4               |
| 2         | 2             | 1                 | 1                 | 0                 | 1                 |
| 3         | 3             | 0                 | 0                 | 2                 | 0.6               |
```

Comment: provide some sample data with your desired output in a table format

Comment: hey @Fahmi i've added some sample data now

Comment: @rajathans can you explain how canceled_count and waitlisted_count contribute to remaining_slots?

Comment: @forpas so when booked count == max_allowed then remaining slots become 0, next bookings start going to waitlist status, if anyone cancels from booked then a waitlist booking changes to booked

Comment: @rajathans see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.*,
  greatest(0, t.max_allowed - t.booked_count + t.canceled_count - t.waitlisted_count) remaining_slots,
  least(t.max_allowed, t.booked_count - t.canceled_count + t.waitlisted_count) / t.max_allowed occupancy_rate 
from (
  select e.id, e.name, e.max_allowed,
    sum(status = 'booked') booked_count,
    sum(status = 'canceled') canceled_count,
    sum(status = 'waitlisted') waitlisted_count
  from Events e left join Bookings b
  on b.event_id = e.id
  group by e.id, e.name, e.max_allowed
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
with src_data as 
(select 
event_id,
sum(case when status='booked' then 1 else 0 end ) as booked_count,
sum(case when status='canceled' then 1 else 0 end ) as canceled_count,
sum(case when status='waitlisted' then 1 else 0 end ) as waitlisted_count
from bookings group by event_id
)

select
s.event_id,
s.booked_count,
s.canceled_count,
s.waitlisted_count,
e.max_allowed-s.booked_count,
s.booked_count/e.max_allowed
from events e inner join src_data s
on e.id=s.event_id;
```